# Setting xpath as value to xslt variable and pass it as a paramter to a JS Function

Tags: variables, xslt

Could you explain how to set `xpath` of a node as the value to a `xslt` variable . I also want to display the value and then pass it as a parameter to a `JS Function`. Thanks for all your Help.

Answer (score 0):

XPath expressions are not values, so they cannot be bound to variables. You can of course put an XPath expression in a string. There's no standard way in XSLT to execute an XPath expression held in a string, but many implementations have an extension function (such as xx:evaluate()) to do it.

It helps to explain what problem you are trying to solve, not what technique you are trying to use to solve it. Then we could suggest alternative and perhaps better approaches.

Comment: I agree with you @Michael .. I wonder what OP wants to do by passing XPath. Anyways I have provided sample code to pass Value of XPath of current node as input argument to JScript.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <child>
    <trial>test</trial>
  </child>
</root>
```

Model code to pass XPath of current node to inline JS function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:js="urn:js">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="js">
    <![CDATA[
      function test(something)
      {
      //code here
      }
     ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="trial">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="xpath">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
            <xsl:value-of select="'/'"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="js:test($xpath)"/> <!--Passed value $xpath to funciton test-->
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

having return value as

```
    return (something);
```

will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <child>
    <trial>root/child/trial</trial>
  </child>
</root>
```